# Linking with a custom external library in CMAKE

Tags: cmake, qt5

There is a project, when building the project has problem with a linking library to the project.
I would be very grateful if someone told me how to solve this problem.
As I understand the problem is in the correct location of the library. So that when build the project correctly linked with it.

This is projects file CmakeList

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(maintenance)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC OFF)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
#set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Charts REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Xml REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Network REQUIRED)

include_directories(../../088)

#include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
#find_library(Network_LIBRARY NAMES NetworkCommunication PATHS ../../088/build-libs-ubuntu-Release)
#find_package_handle_standard_args(Network DEFAULT_MSG Network_LIBRARY)

add_library(NetworkCommunication SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET NetworkCommunication PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../088/build-libs-ubuntu-Release/libNetworkCommunication.so)
set(Network_LIBRARY NetworkCommunication)

#link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../088/build-libs-ubuntu-Release)

qt5_add_resources(RCC_RESOURCES resources.qrc)

file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES_2
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cop/*.h
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cop/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/curves/*.h
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/curves/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/curves/shapes/*.h
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/curves/shapes/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/general/*.h
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/general/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/load_cells/*.h
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/load_cells/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/motors/*.h
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/motors/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/passive_mode/*.h
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/passive_mode/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/settings/*.h
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/settings/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/system/*.h
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/system/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Gener095/Messages/*.h
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Gener095/Messages/*.cpp
        )

set(SOURCE_FILES
        Error.cpp
        Error.hpp
        main.cpp
        MainWindow.cpp
        MainWindow.h
        NetworkCommunicator.cpp
        NetworkCommunicator.h
        Utils.cpp
        Utils.h
        ITab.h
        )

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES_2} ${RCC_RESOURCES})

#target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Network_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} NetworkCommunication)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Charts Qt5::Xml Qt5::Network)

include(../../088/BuildUtilities/scripts/lib_setup.cmake)
```

and logs with errors

```
...
[ 95%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/maintenance.dir/qrc_resources.cpp.o
[ 97%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/maintenance.dir/maintenance_autogen/moc_compilation.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable maintenance
CMakeFiles/maintenance.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o: In function `MainWindow::MainWindow(QMainWindow*)':
/media/blinct/free1/QtProjects/Applications/095/maintenance/MainWindow.cpp:74: undefined reference to `TenzGraphTab::TenzGraphTab(QWidget*)'
CMakeFiles/maintenance.dir/maintenance_autogen/moc_compilation.cpp.o: In function `AngleSensors::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)':
/media/blinct/free1/QtProjects/Applications/095/maintenance/cmake-build-debug/maintenance_autogen/ECUKZBRF6L/moc_AngleSensors.cpp:92: undefined reference to `AngleSensors::OnSetNullPosition()'
/media/blinct/free1/QtProjects/Applications/095/maintenance/cmake-build-debug/maintenance_autogen/ECUKZBRF6L/moc_AngleSensors.cpp:93: undefined reference to `AngleSensors::OnResetAccel()'
/media/blinct/free1/QtProjects/Applications/095/maintenance/cmake-build-debug/maintenance_autogen/ECUKZBRF6L/moc_AngleSensors.cpp:94: undefined reference to `AngleSensors::OnDataReceived(QString, QMap<QString, QVariant>)'
/media/blinct/free1/QtProjects/Applications/095/maintenance/cmake-build-debug/maintenance_autogen/ECUKZBRF6L/moc_AngleSensors.cpp:95: undefined reference to `AngleSensors::OnHandleUp()'
/media/blinct/free1/QtProjects/Applications/095/maintenance/cmake-build-debug/maintenance_autogen/ECUKZBRF6L/moc_AngleSensors.cpp:96: undefined reference to `AngleSensors::OnHandleDown()'
/media/blinct/free1/QtProjects/Applications/095/maintenance/cmake-build-debug/maintenance_autogen/ECUKZBRF6L/moc_AngleSensors.cpp:97: undefined reference to `AngleSensors::OnHandleReleased()'
/media/blinct/free1/QtProjects/Applications/095/maintenance/cmake-build-debug/maintenance_autogen/ECUKZBRF6L/moc_AngleSensors.cpp:98: undefined reference to `AngleSensors::OnHandleTimer()'
CMakeFiles/maintenance.dir/maintenance_autogen/moc_compilation.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV17AngleSensorColumn[_ZTV17AngleSensorColumn]+0x28): undefined reference to `AngleSensorColumn::~AngleSensorColumn()'
CMakeFiles/maintenance.dir/maintenance_autogen/moc_compilation.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV17AngleSensorColumn[_ZTV17AngleSensorColumn]+0x30): undefined reference to `AngleSensorColumn::~AngleSensorColumn()'
CMakeFiles/maintenance.dir/maintenance_autogen/moc_compilation.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV17AngleSensorColumn[_ZTV17AngleSensorColumn]+0x1c0): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to AngleSensorColumn::~AngleSensorColumn()'
CMakeFiles/maintenance.dir/maintenance_autogen/moc_compilation.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV17AngleSensorColumn[_ZTV17AngleSensorColumn]+0x1c8): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to AngleSensorColumn::~AngleSensorColumn()'
../../../088/build-libs-ubuntu-Release/libNetworkCommunication.so: undefined reference to `BtlSerialPortImpl::setRequestToSend(bool)'
../../../088/build-libs-ubuntu-Release/libNetworkCommunication.so: undefined reference to `g_sVersion_NetworkCommunication'
../../../088/build-libs-ubuntu-Release/libNetworkCommunication.so: undefined reference to `BtlUdpSocketImpl::writeDatagram(QByteArray const&, QHostAddress const&, unsigned short)'
../../../088/build-libs-ubuntu-Release/libNetworkCommunication.so: undefined reference to `BtlTcpServerImpl::isListening() const'
../../../088/build-libs-ubuntu-Release/libNetworkCommunication.so: undefined reference to `BtlFileImpl::close()'
../../../088/build-libs-ubuntu-Release/libNetworkCommunication.so: undefined reference to `BtlTcpServerImpl::hasPendingConnections() const'
../../../088/build-libs-ubuntu-Release/libNetworkCommunication.so: undefined reference to `BtlTcpSocketImpl::connectToHost(QHostAddress const&, unsigned short)'
...
../../../088/build-libs-ubuntu-Release/libNetworkCommunication.so: undefined reference to `BtlUdpSocketImpl::readDatagram(char*, long long, QHostAddress*, unsigned short*)'
../../../088/build-libs-ubuntu-Release/libNetworkCommunication.so: undefined reference to `BtlTcpServerImpl::close()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/maintenance.dir/build.make:936: recipe for target 'maintenance' failed
make[3]: *** [maintenance] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/maintenance.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/maintenance.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/maintenance.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/maintenance.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'maintenance' failed
make: *** [maintenance] Error 2
```

Thanks in advance.
For a very long time I can not understand how to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you trying to compile and link to `NetworkCommunication` or is it already installed?

Comment: I compiled NetworkCommunication library but I can't link it to my project.

Comment: `As I understand the problem is in the correct location of the library.` - Linker **finds** the library, but the library doesn't define given symbols (marked as "undefined reference"). Probably, you need some other, additional library to link with. But without knowledge about intention of the library and its code, it is impossible to suggest something definitive.

Answer (score 0):

If NetworkCommunication is something you've written and already have installed, then consider including a `FindNetworkCommunication.cmake` file with the package. That file should contain a method for finding NetworkCommunication like so:

```
# Sets NetworkCommunication_FOUND if found.
#
# If NetworkCommunication_FOUND is TRUE, then the following variables are also
# set: 
#
#    NetworkCommunication_LIBRARY      - Full path to library to link
#    NetworkCommunication_INCLUDE_DIR  - Path to include directory
#
# $NetworkCommunicationDIR is an environment variable that would correspond to the
# ./configure --prefix=$NetworkCommunicationDIR used in building NetworkCommunication.
#

find_path(NetworkCommunication_INCLUDE_DIR NetworkCommunication.h
  HINTS
    ENV NetworkCommunicationDIR
  PATH_SUFFIXES include/NetworkCommunication include/NetworkCommunication include
  PATHS
  /opt/local
  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Alexey\\NetworkCommunication\\1.00.0000;InstallDir]
)

if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
  set(_NetworkCommunication_ARCH_DIR libs/Win64)
else()
  set(_NetworkCommunication_ARCH_DIR libs/Win32)
endif()

find_library(NetworkCommunication_LIBRARY
  NAMES NetworkCommunication
  HINTS
    ENV NetworkCommunicationDIR
  PATH_SUFFIXES lib64 lib libs64 libs ${_NetworkCommunication_ARCH_DIR}
  PATHS
  /opt/local
  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Alexey\\NetworkCommunication\\1.00.0000;InstallDir]
)

unset(_NetworkCommunication_ARCH_DIR)

include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake)
FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(NetworkCommunication  DEFAULT_MSG  NetworkCommunication_LIBRARY NetworkCommunication_INCLUDE_DIR)
mark_as_advanced(NetworkCommunication_LIBRARY NetworkCommunication_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Copy `FindNetworkCommunication.cmake` into the cmake installation's Modules folders (`/usr/share/cmake-3.8/Modules`) or copy it to a local folder and include the path to that folder in `${CMAKE_MODULES_PATH}`.

Next, in your `CMakeLists.txt` file of your **maintenance** project add the following after `add_executable`

```
Find_Package(NetworkCommunication REQUIRED)
if (NetworkCommunication_FOUND)
  target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} ${NetworkCommunication_INCLUDE_DIR})
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${NetworkCommunication_LIBRARY})
endif (NetworkCommunication_FOUND)
```

This is a good solution if **NetworkCommunication** is an independant library which is used by **maintenance** but you intend to have it used by several other libraries too.  If **NetworkCommunication** is part of the same project solution as **maintenance** and is really only meant to be linked to one project ever, then there are probably simpler solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In maintenance.pro for Qt Creator i have this link for this library

```
U_LIB_DIR_PREFIX += ../../088/build-libs
U_LIBS += NetworkCommunication
```

There are many similar libraries for another project and I linked like

```
U_LIBS += NetworkCommunication \
    Logging \
    UnitController \
    TherapyRunnersController \
    GenersControllerCommon
```

All these libraries are build as dynamic libraries. And after this I link this libraries to projects.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is another way how to link library to the project?

Because if you compare this option

```
U_LIB_DIR_PREFIX += ../../088/build-libs-ubuntu-Release
U_LIBS += NetworkCommunication
```

from QtCreator project file maintenance.pro and and writing a module for each library, it turns out very strange and difficult in comparison with 2 lines from *.pro